Terraform error: importing EC2 Key Pair (XXXX): InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair already exists
Terraform newbie here.   I am trying to add an additional node group to existing terraform stack that has already been deployed in AWS region by someone else in my organization.   I have run through the setup and I have edited the terraform.tf file to include my additional node group.  When I come to apply I run into:-
│ Error: importing EC2 Key Pair (XXXXX): InvalidKeyPair.Duplicate: The keypair already exists
│       status code: 400, request id:XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXXX-XXXX-XXXXXX
│
│   with module.networks.aws_key_pair.user,
│   on modules\networks\ec2.tf line 1, in resource "aws_key_pair" "user":
│    1: resource "aws_key_pair" "user" {
Things I checked / tried:-
That the AWS key pairs XXXXX is in my console and there is no duplicates.
Tried the "terraform import" cmd with name | ID from the console but this draws me into a series of questions e.g. Regions, AZs that are already detailed in my script.
Hardwiring my file modules\networks\ec2.tf with the key name and public key(rsa...)
Still not got me cigar so would welcome any suggestions
